# How set id after create new object?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-dropdown, kendo-listview

I create custom button on ListView. Then i create new object, new button has null ID. Please see [snipet](http://dojo.telerik.com/@nim/AsEtU/6).

Steps:

1. Click Create.
2. Fill edit form.
3. Click save.
4. Click options and see alert null;

   ```
           save: function(e)
           {
               // What i can do this, if i know id here?
               e.model.id = ids++;
           },
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically `id` is returned by the server but in your example where the `DataSource` is a local object you can manually assign it *but* you should assign it to the `id` not to `id`. I.e.: in your model definition the `id` is `code` (not `id`) so `save` function should be:

```
save: function(e) {
    e.model.code = ids++;
},
```

Your snippet modified [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/Asalo)

Comment: Your snipet is work but my project not worked. Please see some screens: http://prntscr.com/5iogss  http://prntscr.com/5iohwx http://prntscr.com/5ioip9  http://prntscr.com/5ioj8i

Comment: I found problem. in save function i make async ajax request, to store data on server. If i make sync request it,s ok. How i can use async ?

Comment: Why do not implement the `update` method in your `datastore` definition? Then, when the ajax async call finished you invoke `op.success` with the argument that is the object with the final `id` (note: `op` is the argument of your `update` method).

Comment: You mean rebuild datasource and interface?

Comment: Can you get any link for a similar example. I probably want a lot, but I strive to write code more competent.